# Duplicate content when using append() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I used to append content to page using javascript and jQuery, it works fine at Chrome, but when trying it with Firefox it duplicates the appended content.

Here is an example:
[image: duplicate appeneded content]

I use this code to append content to a div:

```
function PlayGames() {
    $(".gameActions, #flash-game").show();
    $(".TheGame").show().append("<object id='flash-game' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' height='100%' width='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' data='URL'>");
        }
```

Don't know why this happens only in Firefox and IE sometimes.
Here is the complete javascript code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script>        
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
          $("TheGame").hide();
        });
        window.onload = function(){
         var mainDiv = $( "games" );
        }

        var isShowAd = '1';

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (typeof(Noads) === 'undefined') {
                $(".AdBlock").hide();
            }
        });

        function PlayBtn() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'TheURL',
            });
            $(".TheGameInfo").hide();
            if (!isShowAd) {
                PlayGames();
            } else {
                if (typeof (Noads) === 'undefined') {
                    $(".TheGameInfo,.AdBlock").show();
                } else {
                    StartPlayAds();
                }
            }
        }

        function StartPlayAds() {
            var SizeWindow =$('.TheGame');
            var Height = $(SizeWindow).innerHeight();
            var Width = $(SizeWindow).innerWidth();
            $(SizeWindow).append("<div id='mainContainer'><div id='ContentElementBox'><video id='contentElement'></video></div><div id='adContainer'></div></div>").trigger('create');
            try {
                var googleAds = new GoogleAds(
                    document.getElementById('adContainer'),
                    document.getElementById('contentElement'),
                    Width, Height,
                    function (action) {
                        if (action === GoogleAds.CallbackAction.CONTENT_PLAY) {
                            $("#mainContainer").remove();
                            PlayGames();
                        }
                    });
                googleAds.playAds();
            } catch (e) {
                $("#mainContainer").remove();
                PlayGames();
            }
        }

        function PlayGames() {
            $(".gameActions, #flash-game").show();
            $(".TheGame").show().append("<object id='flash-game' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' height='100%' width='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' data='URL'>");
        }

        function RefreshGame() {
            $("#flash-game").remove();
            StartPlayAds();
        }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: if the effect is the call of the PlayGames function, who is calling? Santa ?

Comment: I have edited the question by adding the complete js code.

Comment: if googleAds.playAds(); produces an error then PlayGames() is called 2 times

Comment: but it won't!!!, also, it does not occur in Chrome, only Firefox, and IE!, I checked Firefox console and there are no errors.

Comment: Yes, you may be right! it only occurs when I click SKIP ADS button only, When I reloaded the page and waited for the ADS to end peacefully without any interruption, there are no duplicates!!!

Comment: you can see the loadads.js file here:
https://www.al3abmizo.com/js/loadads.js

I doubt in this function, it won't be written carefully...

```GoogleAds.prototype.playAds = function () {
    var self = this;

    if (this.waitLoadingTimer != null)
        return;```

Comment: Also, I am using this API:
//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js

which contain the skip function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured it out!!! anyone facing such issue please read this. When the **SKIP ADS** button clicked the **.append() function** appends a repeated element like an iframe, DIV or whatever else in my case an iframe.

My old code was only checking if the #mainContainer exists then remove it and start playing the game, the procedures as follow:

```
function (action) {
 if (action === GoogleAds.CallbackAction.CONTENT_PLAY) {
    $("#mainContainer").remove();
    PlayGames();
 }
```

So, I tried to include the main game iframe ID **(which causes the repeat issue)** and it works fine, when the **AD SKIPPED** the iframe will be removed either as follow:

```
function (action) {
 if (action === GoogleAds.CallbackAction.CONTENT_PLAY) {
    $("#mainContainer, #flash-game").remove();
    PlayGames();
 }
```

Now, it's working perfectly exactly as needed.

Thank you.